# The panel text is larger than normal on 20.04 after removing KDE

Tags: gnome, 20.04, kde, panel

On 20.04 I recently removed KDE and an attempted install of polybar and returned to pure gnome. Now my panel (the top bar) has larger text. If I disable and enable large text the problem is persistent and I am unsure on how to solve this.

Comment: The amount of detail provided in this question is not really enough to determine the exact cause. A DE is comprised of dozens and dozens of packages.  Changing desktop environments on an installed system is **messy**.  That's why Ubuntu maintains several distinct flavors.  Kubuntu is the official flavor of Ubuntu that uses KDE.  Now that doesn't mean you can't troubleshoot and possibly fix this issue, but it will involve a lot of digging/research on your part to find out what package(s) or config(s) are problematic out of the hundreds affected by a DE swap

Comment: Specify how you disable and enable large text? What setting do you use to change that?